# Julia & Cygwin - Can't find all packages

Tags: cygwin, package, julia

The workstation I have in the office runs Windows 7, so I have relied on [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) to provide some of the tools to which I have grown accustomed.  Among other things, I have installed [Julia](http://julialang.org/).  To access it within Cygwin, I just created a link to the install location and placed it in my path.  (This is to highlight that there are not two separate installs.)

```
% whereis julia
julia: /usr/local/bin/julia

% ls -l /usr/local/bin
total 13
-rwxr-xr-x 1 USER Domain Users 10572 Jul 17 09:09 apt-cyg
lrwxrwxrwx 1 USER Domain Users    57 Jul 22 08:53 julia -> /c/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Julia-0.3.10/bin/julia.exe
```

The thing is, there seems to be a disparity between the available packages when Julia is opened up in DOS versus Cygwin.  When I open a DOS prompt and navigate to the location referenced in the link above, I get the following output from `Pkg.update()`:

```
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.10 (2015-06-24 13:54 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-w64-mingw32

julia> Pkg.status()
34 required packages:
 - Bootstrap                     0.3.1
 - Calculus                      0.1.9
 - Clustering                    0.4.0
 - ColorBrewer                   0.1.1
 - Combinatorics                 0.1.2
 - Convex                        0.0.6
 - Cpp                           0.1.0
 - Curl                          0.0.3
 - DataFramesMeta                0.0.1
 - DataStructures                0.3.11
 - DictUtils                     0.0.2
 - Distance                      0.5.1
 - FixedEffectModels             0.0.3
 - GLM                           0.4.6
 - GLMNet                        0.0.4
 - Gadfly                        0.3.13
 - IJulia                        0.2.5
 - Images                        0.4.41
 - Ito                           0.0.2
 - Jewel                         1.0.5
 - KernelDensity                 0.1.1
 - MultivariateStats             0.2.1
 - Pandas                        0.2.0
 - PyPlot                        1.5.3
 - QuantEcon                     0.2.0
 - RCall                         0.2.1
 - RDatasets                     0.1.2
 - Shapefile                     0.0.2
 - SortingAlgorithms             0.0.5
 - Sparklines                    0.1.0
 - Stan                          0.2.0
 - Stats                         0.1.0
 - StatsBase                     0.7.0
 - SymPy                         0.2.28
67 additional packages:
 - ArrayViews                    0.6.2
 - BinDeps                       0.3.14
 - Blosc                         0.1.2
 - Cairo                         0.2.28
 - Calendar                      0.4.3
 - Codecs                        0.1.4
 - Color                         0.4.7
 - Compat                        0.4.10
 - Compose                       0.3.13
 - Contour                       0.0.7
 - DSP                           0.0.9
 - DataArrays                    0.2.17
 - DataFrames                    0.6.8
 - Dates                         0.3.2
 - Distances                     0.2.0
 - Distributions                 0.8.2
 - Docile                        0.5.13
 - DualNumbers                   0.1.3
 - FactCheck                     0.3.1
 - FixedPointNumbers             0.0.9
 - Formatting                    0.1.3
 - GZip                          0.2.17
 - Graphics                      0.1.0
 - Graphs                        0.5.5
 - Grid                          0.3.10
 - HDF5                          0.5.1
 - Hexagons                      0.0.3
 - ICU                           0.4.4
 - ImmutableArrays               0.0.8
 - IterationManagers             0.0.1
 - Iterators                     0.1.8
 - JLD                           0.5.0
 - JSON                          0.4.4
 - JuliaParser                   0.6.2
 - LNR                           0.0.1
 - LaTeXStrings                  0.1.3
 - Lazy                          0.9.1
 - Lexicon                       0.1.14
 - LibExpat                      0.0.8
 - LightGraphs                   0.2.1
 - LightXML                      0.1.12
 - Loess                         0.0.3
 - MAT                           0.2.12
 - MacroTools                    0.1.0
 - Mamba                         0.4.12
 - MathProgBase                  0.3.14
 - NaNMath                       0.0.2
 - Nettle                        0.1.10
 - NumericFuns                   0.2.3
 - Optim                         0.4.2
 - PDMats                        0.3.5
 - Polynomial                    0.1.1
 - Polynomials                   0.0.3
 - PyCall                        0.8.2
 - REPLCompletions               0.0.3
 - Reexport                      0.0.2
 - Requires                      0.1.3
 - SHA                           0.0.4
 - SIUnits                       0.0.4
 - Showoff                       0.0.4
 - StatsFuns                     0.1.1
 - TexExtensions                 0.0.2
 - URIParser                     0.0.5
 - WinRPM                        0.1.10
 - WoodburyMatrices              0.1.1
 - ZMQ                           0.1.19
 - Zlib                          0.1.8
```

By contrast, when I call `julia` from Cygwin, I only get a subset of packages:

```
   _       _ _(_)_     |  A fresh approach to technical computing
  (_)     | (_) (_)    |  Documentation: http://docs.julialang.org
   _ _   _| |_  __ _   |  Type "help()" for help.
  | | | | | | |/ _` |  |
  | | |_| | | | (_| |  |  Version 0.3.10 (2015-06-24 13:54 UTC)
 _/ |\__'_|_|_|\__'_|  |  Official http://julialang.org/ release
|__/                   |  x86_64-w64-mingw32

julia> using QuantEcon
ERROR: QuantEcon not found
 in require at loading.jl:47

julia> Pkg.status()
3 required packages:
 - Distributions                 0.8.2
 - Gadfly                        0.3.13
 - IJulia                        0.2.5
42 additional packages:
 - ArrayViews                    0.6.2
 - BinDeps                       0.3.14
 - Calculus                      0.1.9
 - Codecs                        0.1.4
 - Color                         0.4.7
 - Compat                        0.4.10
 - Compose                       0.3.13
 - Contour                       0.0.7
 - DataArrays                    0.2.17
 - DataFrames                    0.6.8
 - DataStructures                0.3.11
 - Dates                         0.3.2
 - Distances                     0.2.0
 - Docile                        0.5.13
 - DualNumbers                   0.1.3
 - FixedPointNumbers             0.0.9
 - GZip                          0.2.17
 - Graphics                      0.1.0
 - Grid                          0.3.10
 - Hexagons                      0.0.3
 - ImmutableArrays               0.0.8
 - Iterators                     0.1.8
 - JSON                          0.4.4
 - KernelDensity                 0.1.1
 - LibExpat                      0.0.8
 - Loess                         0.0.3
 - NaNMath                       0.0.2
 - Nettle                        0.1.10
 - Optim                         0.4.2
 - PDMats                        0.3.5
 - REPLCompletions               0.0.3
 - Reexport                      0.0.2
 - SHA                           0.0.4
 - Showoff                       0.0.4
 - SortingAlgorithms             0.0.5
 - StatsBase                     0.7.0
 - StatsFuns                     0.1.1
 - URIParser                     0.0.5
 - WinRPM                        0.1.10
 - WoodburyMatrices              0.1.1
 - ZMQ                           0.1.19
 - Zlib                          0.1.8
```

What appears to be happening is that a separate `.julia/` directory is being created within the Cygwin file tree space.  If I install a package on the DOS side, it does not update this collection (and vice versa).  This would be just fine except that I prefer navigating through Cygwin, and not all packages will successfully install through the Cygwin version of Julia.  (For example, [QuantEcon](https://github.com/QuantEcon/QuantEcon.jl) will install just fine on the DOS side, but gets hung up on `"Building Blosc"` on the Cygwin side.)  Cygwin already points to the same executable as DOS, but is there a way to point the Cygwin version at the DOS package collection?  I suppose I could just manually copy the packages over, but this kind of hackery seems inefficient (and annoying).  I suspect there is a simple solution I have not yet found.

**UPDATE**

Here is the path from `Pkg.dir()` from both sides:

DOS: "C:\Users\USER\.julia\v0.3"

Cygwin: "C:\cygwin64\home\USER\.julia\v0.3"

Comment: Can you run `Pkg.dir()` in both setups to see the paths it is using?

Comment: Of course, please see the update, and thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It seems like you have entirely different package repositories then, depending on what your home environment variable is set to. I'd suggest setting the JULIA_PKGDIR environment variable in both environments to ensure you get the same each time.

Comment: These variables do not currently exist.  Does Julia look for them if they are created?  Or do I need to do something else?

Comment: Correct, they don't exist, but will be looked for if they do exist.